# How do I find the private git repository URL?

Tags: github, repository

[image]

Where in my repository under the code it's not showing any URL

Answer (score 1):

It is usually `git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git`

In command line you have to go to your project directory and type:

```
git init
```

This is going to initialise Git in you project directory

To add your project to Git you have to add a commit

```
git add .
```

followed by your commit message

```
git commit -m "<message>"
```

message can be anything you want to write to identify that commit... You can write `First commit` for example

After that you will want to set your origin url

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<organisation_name>/<reponame>.git
```

The `organisation_name` is most probably the account that created the repo

With your origin set you can push it to Git:

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Even for private repository? because when I saw in tutorials for public repository  it was showing the URL under the code section which confuses me.

Comment: Even in private, but it is going to ask you for your password and check if you have access to the private repo. You can add your SSH key to the repo to avoid be typing your password all the time

Comment: As my private repository has been created by my organization and I have been invited to github to access the repository. As I need to move my eclipse project to the given github repository.

Will I be able to do it? or I need to contact the admin for it?

Comment: Sorry... I misunderstood... your organisation create the git repo, but the project is in your machine, correct?

Comment: Yes it's in my machine